# ExtJs - How to load json file using extjs with the Ext.Ajax.request method?

Tags: ajax, json, model-view-controller, extjs

I wish to load a json file using extjs. Previously I was loading my json file with the help of jquery library as below:

```
Ext.define('app.store.Students', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'app.model.Student',
    storeId: 'StudentData',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data/users.json',
        success: function(resp) {
        console.log(resp.responseText);
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'student1',
            model: 'app.model.Student',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
    }
});
```

But now I want to load my json file using ExtJs. I tried the below code:

```
Ext.define('app.store.Students', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'app.model.Student',
    storeId: 'StudentData',
    autoLoad: true,
});
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'data/users.json',
    //method: 'GET',
    success: function(response){
        var text = response.responseText;
        alert('1')
        console.log(this.url);
        // process server response here
    }
});
```

but it says 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined'. When inspected in firebug, the url given below is undefined in ext-all-debug.js.

```
    urlAppend : function(url, string) {
    if (!Ext.isEmpty(string)) {
    return url + (url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&') + string;
    }
    return url;
    },
```

I tried to console the url as given above in Ext.Ajax.request method, it says url is undefined. Where am I going wrong?

FYI: This is my file structure:

```
-html file
-data folder - users.json
-app folder - store folder - js file (This is where I use my Ext.Ajax.request method)
```

Am I going wrong in the relative path? If so, how I should use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If data is not specified, and if **autoLoad** is **true** or an Object, this store's load method is automatically called after creation.Either set **autoLoad** to **false** or use **proxy** with type ajax and reader and then a callback function to handle your json data.

> Update : Try this

```
Ext.define('app.store.Students', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'app.model.Student',
storeId: 'StudentData',
autoLoad: true,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'app/data/users.json',
    reader:{
        type: 'json',
        root: 'student1'//If you are using student1 as root.
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried setting autoLoad to false. I dont get the error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined' anymore. But, I still cant get the datas loaded in my page. I mean the url is wrong. I'm using my relative path : ' url: 'data/users.json','. Is this wrong?

Comment: structure should be :
app folder->stores,
          data folder,
          models,
          views
I mean all the above should be in your app folder.

Comment: Now that I have placed data, model, view, store, controller inside my app folder and have used the 'url: 'app/data/users.json', still my grid doesn't load the datas :( and the console.log(this.url) is still undefined. :(